# setting dual boot on a system with window 8 and ubuntu installed on different patitions

Tags: dual-boot, window

Note: I have seen some post on how to install ubuntu on a windows 8 pc. 
I think this problem might be different.

I created 4 partitions on my hard drive so that 
I can put windows 8 in one partition,
Ubuntu in the second partition,
The third is the swap space,
The fourth is to keep my files.

I was hoping to save files on the fourth partition from both Ubuntu and windows os.

First I installed ubuntu and it worked. I was able to boot the os. But then I noticed the other partitions 
(first partition  and files partition) were not displayed in Ubuntu.

Then I installed windows 8 and noticed the same thing. The partitions (Ubuntu and files partitions) were not displayed also.

After installing windows 8 the system boots to windows 8 with out options to choose either os.

note: the partition for swap space was not displayed either but I figure it wasn't supposed to display on the os as a partition.

What should I do to fix it ?.
Should I just format the drive and start again ?.

Comment: You should install Windows 8 first and then install Ubuntu. and for the partitions not showing issue, can you tell what file system you used to partition the hdd ? And one thing, you cant see the ubuntu partition on windows 8 because windows cant recognize the ext partitions with out installing special drivers.

Comment: The file system for windows 8 is NTFS,   the other partitions are ext4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Avishek, you first need to install Windows then Ubuntu, i would recommend you to do a clean install and partition you disk in windows.

The partition you which you want to save your data files, make sure you change it to logical else there will be a problem when you install Ubuntu, the problem here is that when you install windows it actually creates two partition one named "reserved system partition" and other is your "C:" drive, both will be primary partition and Ubuntu root directory and swap area partitions will also be Primary partitions. If your using MS-DOS Partition table you cannot have more then 4 primary partitions, so its always good to make a logical partition.

So, you will have 4 Primary partition with 1 Extended partition(Logical).

Now Install Ubuntu normally, set Swap area and enjoy your Dual Boot System.

Comment: Thank a lot. It worked but I have another issue. When I try to open the partition(device) for windows or my files I get an error message with the title **UNABLE TO ACCESS "[THE-VOLUME-LABEL]"** and a description that says _Error mounting /dev/sda5 at /media/harrison/Bench: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o_ and a message that says _exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount..._ I shutdown windows properly before booting ubuntu. What can I do to fix this.

Comment: Boot to windows and disable, fast boot under power options. What this option does is, it doesn't shut down your system completely rather it saves the state of your machine, so next time when you boot it just loads the previous state, which results in booting faster. If this doesn't solve I would recommend you to completely remove the hibernate in windows. Also whenever you want to boot to Ubuntu do a clean shutdown on windows and boot to Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Both Ubuntu and windows are working perfectly now.

Comment: Then select this as a answere

Comment: @user3557759, if this answer helped you out, mark it as answer. so that other who has same problem can easy make use of it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with windows 8 and later windows products is that they use UEFI-GPT partition tables. While this partition table format is a much needed improvement over the BIOS-MBR partition table and firmware scheme, it still has compatibility issues with some OSes and hardware - especially older hardware. Older hardware don't have support for UEFI and by extension GPT - which is the only partition table that Windows 8 can be installed on. While Recent Ubuntu versions on newer machines work flawlessly with UEFI and GPT, older Ubuntu versions running on older hardware still need the older MBR partition table format - which is something that can not be since windows 8 only works on GPT.